# returning a reference to a slice using named return values in Golang

Tags: go, return-value

I have this piece of code, which returns a reference to a slice:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type V2BucketAccess struct {
    BucketName   string
    AccessPolicy string
}

func main() {
    result := MyFunc()
    fmt.Print(*result)
}

func MyFunc() *[]V2BucketAccess {
    parsedBucketsNames := []V2BucketAccess{}
    mystuff1 := V2BucketAccess{
        BucketName:   "bucket-1",
        AccessPolicy: "readwrite",
    }
    mystuff2 := V2BucketAccess{
        BucketName:   "bucket-2",
        AccessPolicy: "read",
    }
    parsedBucketsNames = append(parsedBucketsNames, mystuff1, mystuff2)
    return &parsedBucketsNames
}
```

I wanted to rewrite this using named return values, and I came up with something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type V2BucketAccess struct {
    BucketName   string
    AccessPolicy string
}

func main() {
    result := MyFunc()
    fmt.Print(*result)
}

func MyFunc() (parsedBucketsNames *[]V2BucketAccess) {
    *parsedBucketsNames = []V2BucketAccess{}
    mystuff1 := V2BucketAccess{
        BucketName:   "bucket-1",
        AccessPolicy: "readwrite",
    }
    mystuff2 := V2BucketAccess{
        BucketName:   "bucket-2",
        AccessPolicy: "read",
    }
    *parsedBucketsNames = append(*parsedBucketsNames, mystuff1, mystuff2)
    return
}
```

However, this generates a segmentation violation on the first line of the MyFunc() function. What would be the correct way to do this via named return values, or is this one of those cases where named return values shouldn't be used? An explanation why my solution generates a segmentation fault is very welcome.

Comment: A pointer is not a reference. Pointers to slices are needed very rarely. Just use `parsedBucketsNames = &[]V2BucketAccess{}`. You seem to struggle with the concept of a pointer and a pointer variabel. Maybe redoing the Tour of Go might be an option.

Comment: @Volker I fail to see the error in my attempt, could you please explain what the mistake is in the second piece of code?I only encountered this issue when using named return values, and I don't recall the Tour of Go explaining returning pointers to slices using named return variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In return declaration `parsedBucketsNames *[]V2BucketAccess1` is given `nil` value. This line

```
*parsedBucketsNames = []V2BucketAccess{}
```

is the same as

```
var parsedBucketsNames *[]V2BucketAccess
*parsedBucketsNames = []V2BucketAccess{}
```

Using `*` on a nil pointer makes the program crash with segmentation violation. You must not dereference the pointer so early. To assign a value you must obtain the address of the literal

```
parsedBucketsNames = &[]V2BucketAccess{}
```

I fixed your code here https://go.dev/play/p/AU5InoPWFJW